# static content 404 magento2

Tags: magento2, installation

I installed Magento2.3 and got greeted with the usual style not loading errors. I looked at the url it was trying to load and it was going to `en_GB`, which was 404'ing. Inspecting the `pub/static` directory showed that the deploy command worked for the `en_US` directory.

So I tried this command to resolve the issue:

```
$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_GB
```

and inspecting the `en_GB` directory in the `pub/static` directory shows that the generation worked. I then went to my site and it still 404s.

I've tried:

```
$ rm -rf var/
```

and

```
$ php bin/magento cache:flush
$ php bin/magento indexer:reindex
$ chmod -R 777 pub/
```

but still the same result. What am I doing wrong? (fresh install so no code changes thus far)

Comment: Are you able to open admin properly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure apache “rewrite_module” is enable and then restart the server.

If this hasn't worked. Then do following steps:

Edit the file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.
Find this code:

```
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
```

Change "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All".

```
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
```

Restart apache2.

Comment: Allowoverride was already set to all but missing the rewrite module^^

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps.

Step 1: Below command will remove all auto generated files and folders.

```
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/* pub/static/adminhtml/* var/{cache,composer_home,page_cache,view_preprocesseds,di} generation/*
```

Step 2: Run setup upgrade command.

```
php bin/magento s:up
```

Step 3: Run satic content deploy command. Below comand will create static files for en_US and en_GB.

```
php bin/magento s:static-content:de -f en_US en_GB
```

Step 4: Give the permission to auto generated folders.

```
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
```

If permission require sudo user then add prefix as sudo.

Above commands might be helps you.